# How to find the derivative of function using given functional equation?

Tags: functional-equations

$$f \left(\frac{x+y}{2} \right) = \frac{f(x)+f(y)}{2}, \forall x,y \in \mathbb{R}$$

$$f'(0)= -1,\space f(0)=1$$

$$f'(u)=?$$

Comment: Just differentiate the functional equation with respect to $y$ and put $y=0$.

Comment: Well, the first step should be to prove that it's differentiable at all, and not only for $x=0$. But why do you need that, is it homework, or something important?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Prove first that $f(-x)=2-f(x)$. Then,
$$\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}=\frac{f(x+h)+f(-x)-2}{h}=\frac{2f(\frac{h}{2})-2}{h}.$$

I let you conclude. This will prove the derivability and it will gives you the value of $f'(x)$ for all $x$.